# Wrong key type in Map not discovered during compile-time. Is Apex really type-safe?

Tags: apex

This bug makes me shiver a bit ;) I expected Apex to be a type-safe language, that would warn me during compile-time when I do this:

```
// Create a map with keys of type STRING
Map<String, String> myMap = new Map<String, String>();
myMap.put('key', 'value'); 

// Loop over Keyset but use wrong type Id
for(Id key : myMap.keySet()) {
   System.debug('#' + key);
}
```

BUT. It perfectly compiles. I spend the last hours to find out why production code ran into errors and accidentally discovered that the loop part should instead be like this:

```
// Loop over Keyset NOW use correct type String
for(String key : myMap.keySet()) {
   System.debug('#' + key);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Apex is type safe, except this is a bit of a strange one.

Id is not a concrete type, it cannot be constructed.

```
String str = new String('Hello world');
Id id = str;
```

This would attempt to do an implicit casting from String to Id, *because some instances of Strings can be Ids*. However it would result in a runtime exception since str is not an Id.

My understanding is that its a bit like this

```
public abstract class Parent{}

public class Child extends Parent{}

public class Grandchild extends Parent{}

Parent child = new Child();
Grandchild gc = (Grandchild) child;
```

This would still compile, but the casting only happens at runtime and is therefore a Runtime exception.

Comment: This is right. Id is a very strange type that strings are automatically coerced into (or a runtime exception is thrown). I suspect in the compiled bytecode ID types are actually strings but with a valdiation on set for ensure their format is valid. I'm not aware of any other types that behave like this in apex.

Answer (score 3):

This is what Salesforce Support wrote me. I pretty confirms what all the other answers already stated:

> As we had a discussion on call I informed you that primitive data
>   types String and Id can be use interchangeably to assign the values as
>   mentioned below however, at compile time if it doesn't found the id in
>   proper format an error is produce.
>
> Id d='006900000049BDU'; String ss=d; Id d2=ss;
>
> Here if we assign id d2='abc' at compile time there would be no error
>   but at run time it will verify for the format of id and throw error.
>
> As discussed you gave me consent to close the case for now, I will go
>   ahead with case closure however, for any queries regarding the case
>   feel free to contact us and we will be glad to help.
>
> Regards
>
> Developer Support Engineer